# How to use Observable.if correctly in redux-observable?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, react-redux, rxjs5, redux-observable

I am trying to use `Observable.if` in redux-observable to determine which action to dispatch.

In the case below, I expected it dispatch `SIGN_OUT`. However, it does not dispatch any action.

How can I use it correctly? Thanks

```
export const initEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$
    .ofType(INIT)
    .mergeMap(() =>
      Observable.if(
        () => true,
        { type: SIGN_OUT },
        { type: START_SOMETHING }
      ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two parameters to `Observable.if` should be Observables so you should be using it like:

```
Observable.if(
  () => true,
  Observable.of({ type: SIGN_OUT }),
  Observable.of({ type: START_SOMETHING })
));
```